# How certificate pinning works in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to phonegap development.

I am facing problem while using below plugin

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

I am not getting server fingerprints because of I am using Self-Signed certificate at server side.

My doubts are regarding this plugin are:

1. As i understand i am not getting fingerprints because of Self-Signed Certificate to resolve this i have used android code to enter your certificate in android truststore
   after that i am getting fingerprints.
2. If i get fingerprint in native by above process then how it will work in PhoneGap because android webview is written in c++(as described by phonegap site).

**My task is to create ajax and web-socket connection in PhoneGap where server certificate is self signed so i am trying to use certificate pinning.**

Comment: You can try this link ---- 

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?